# MATLAB - Cleanly read variables out of a function possibly using some type of varargout...?

Tags: matlab, variables

I have function f1 which must contain subfunctions, so I can't use another script:

```
function vars = f1()

    a = 1;
    b = 'hello';
    c = {[1 2 3]};

    currvars = whos;    %all variable info
    for k = 1:size(currvars, 1)
        eval(['vars.(currvars(k).name) = ' currvars(k).name ';']);
    end

end
```

I call the function in a script, and then I create the variables in the script using genvarname() and eval():

```
vars = f1();
varnames = genvarname(fieldnames(vars));
for k = 1:size(varnames(:),1)    %Creates vars with the struct's fieldnames.
    eval([varnames{k} ' = vars.' varnames{k} ';']);
end
clearvars vars varnames
```

I'd like to fit the variable creation process into a function somehow while reading out all the variables only to the script calling it, but I don't want to assign a hundred different variable names to the output. Does anyone have any advice on how to do this?

Comment: might be an idea to tag it with the language or mention it in the title.

Comment: my first question. thanks for the heads up paul!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CREDIT TO RODY...

```
#Old semi-"global" variables:

function vars = f1()

    a = 1;
    b = 'hello';
    c = {[1 2 3]};
    currvars = whos;    %all variable info
    for k = 1:size(currvars, 1)
       eval(['vars.(currvars(k).name) = ' currvars(k).name ';']);
    end

end

#Function to assign variables to the calling script's/function's workspace. Variable names are determined by the single structure's fieldnames:
function setvars(func)

    vars = func;
    protected = {'If needed, put variable names you do not want here'};
    names    = fieldnames(vars);
    newnames = genvarname(names, protected);
    for k = 1:numel(newnames)
        assignin('caller', newnames{k}, vars.(names{k}));
    end

end

#Script call:

setvars(f1);
```

Answer (score 1):

DON'T CREATE zillions of automatically named variables. This is foolish and terribly poor programming style. Instead, learn to use arrays. Multidimensional arrays, cell arrays, struct arrays.

Or, do what you have done, and then be forced to find a kludge like you are looking for.

Take your pick. Eval is evil.

Comment: I need to do this because I'm editing old 2004 code that already has these varialbes assigned and is just a wall of text. I'm trying to clean it up a little at a time. If anyone has comments that are constructive, please reply.

Comment: @JasonGarcia : I am inclined to agree with woodchips here. By taking this variable-generation approach you will very likely cause more headache for yourself in the future. If your situation really requires this kind of approach, please explain more clearly in the original question what you are trying to do and why this approach is obligatory.

Comment: This request is needed because I'm dealing with spaghetti code. There are numerous scripts that call even more scripts. I'm trying to narrow down which variables are defined where and categorize the code into functions. I can't eliminate variable names until i know where they are used. I wanted to create the functions first to possibly make the clean-up easier. I also agree that arrays are easier to interpret, but the fact of the matter is the code was already written.

Comment: Still ... Use a struct or a cell array. To be honest, you will likely be better off re-writing large pieces of spaghetti code completely, than wasting your time to untangle crap spaghetti. Working with that code will simply create bugs you cannot then repair without a huge further investment. In the end, the time spent writing something good will be well worth it.

Comment: If you really insist on doing this, do as I said. Create a single struct variable, as a container for all of this crap. You will learn to regret that of course, compared to having just biting the bullet and doing a major rewrite.

Comment: With all due respect, just deciding to rewrite code that was developed over the span of five years doesn't get decided over a forum. I agree with the opinion that this is a kludge, but I'd really appreciate any ideas as to how to resolve my question.

Comment: Sigh. Did I not tell you what to do if you will persist in this kludge? (AND I'VE NOW SAID IT SEVERAL TIMES.) Stuff them all into a struct. Still, you would be surprised, that rewriting what you have into something that is well thought out will NOT take 5 years to re-write. It probably took 5 years to write because they had no idea how to write code, and then kept piling crap on top of crap. Each mod they made took longer and longer to do.

Comment: @woodchips Just because I like throwing oil on fire: *you don't know this*. For all you know, only this tiny part is spaghetti while the rest is the best Matlab code you've ever seen. Moreover, suggesting to change old, terrible but working code is not the best advice I've ever seen you give someone.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis - Sorry, but that is incredibly silly of you. If only ONE small part is spaghetti code, then it is absolutely foolish to NOT fix it, rather than creating a kludge. If this person is tasked with maintaining the code, then they will greatly benefit from fixing it, so that they understand how to maintain it for the future. If they refuse to do so, then I told them exactly what to do. So what part of that advice is not good? You don't maintain spaghetti code, you just pray that it stays working.

Comment: A big reason spaghetti tends to grow, is you start with a small tool, not really well thought out, and written by someone who does not know programming well. (That is why it is spaghetti after all.) The tool gets used heavily, and expands to add features. These features don't really work well unless you do some kludgy fixes to your old code. So kludge gets piled on top of kludge. In the end, you have something that can be re-written in a few days as clean code, that runs faster, more efficiently, and is maintainable. Or you can add another kludge on top. I've seen it happen many times.

Comment: Can anyone say "slippery slope"? :) Still, it sounds like you speak from personal experience, which does **not** allow you to make a generalization to everyone's situation. For all you know, the OP has a piece of spaghetti code of 250,000 lines, which is part of a much better written framework consisting of 3.5 million lines. You also don't know how long full-scale testing takes in something like that. You know just as well as I do that it is a horrible practice to just start rewriting massive amounts of the spaghetti.

Comment: It is much better practice to take *extremely* small steps, and test each one of them carefully. The teeny tiny step the OP wants to take here indicates that at least part of what I say is correct.

Comment: Completely true :) In my situation rewritting the code would take too long and is unacceptable. Deadlines...

Answer (score 0):

You could return a structure with "corrected" fieldnames:

```
function output = someFunc

    vars = f1();

    protected = { %# some list of varnames you don't want
    };

    names    = fieldnames(vars);
    newnames = genvarname(names, protected);

    for k = 1:numel(newnames)
        output.(newnames{k}) = vars.(names{k});            
    end

end
```

If you then use

```
output = someFunc;
varnames = fieldnames(output);
for k = 1:numel(fieldnames)
    eval([varnames{k} ' = output.' varnames{k} ';']);
end
```

in the script/function where you want the variable names, you have a relatively clean way of locking everything up in the function `someFunc` without having to pre-define all output variable names.

You can also do this in one step:

```
function someFunc2

    vars = f1();

    protected = { %# some list of varnames you don't want
    };

    names    = fieldnames(vars);
    newnames = genvarname(names, protected);

    for k = 1:numel(newnames)
        assignin('caller', newnames{k}, vars.(names{k}));
    end

end
```

Which means you just call the function

```
someFunc2;
```

in your script, and the function then defines and assigns all the variables *in the script's workspace*.

A tiny step forward, but forward nonetheless :)

Comment: I think the problem is that he needs the variables to be available in the workspace, since they are used by other parts of his code. Having a structure would then require extracting the structure fields and assigning them to actual variables, so that the code works.

Comment: @angainor: Yes, I see your point. I've edited my post to reflect it.